# Add Action (-Button) to Attributes Form (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, actions, forms

Is it possible, to *simply* add a Action to a Attribute Form (Drag'n Drop Designer)? I know, I could use the QT-Designer and Python, but I'm looking for a *fast and simple* way without python knowledge.

And to get further: the Action should be used to delete the current feature.

[image]

Comment: If you need to ask a follow up question using Python then, for questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.